# TWTRLogInButton (Twitter Login Button) set title causes overlapping text

Tags: ios, twitter

`TWTRLoginButton` is supposed to inherit from `UIButton`, but when I use `setTitle:forState` I end up with overlapping text like so:
[image]
What I'm doing:

```
@IBAction func twitterLoginButtonPressed(sender: TWTRLogInButton) {

  twitterLoginButton.logInCompletion = {(session:TWTRSession!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    }

    if session != nil {
        self.session = session
        self.twitterLoginButton.setTitle("Logged in as \(session.userName)", forState: .Normal)
    }
  }
}
```

It's like they've added a label to the view hierarchy, instead of using the built-in API. But [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrloginbutton) don't say anything about this or how to use it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they're add custom label to the button as you think. And there is no API to customize it. If you really want to do it, need to dig the view hierarchy.

Like bellow:

```
twitterLoginButton.logInCompletion = {(session:TWTRSession!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
      println(error)
  }

  if session != nil {
      self.session = session

      // Digging the view hierarchy
      var view = twitterLoginButton.subviews.last as UIView
      var label = view.subviews.first as UILabel
      label.text = "Logged in as \(session.userName)"
  }
}
```

It goes without saying, it will not work if view hierarchy will change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

@buildsucceeded

It's Possible with a very straight forward way!!! Even its documented in fabric(twitter mobile SDK) documents.

You can customize the look & feel of the TWTRLogInButton - which is the login button provided by twitter itself. But you can have your own as well. What you just need to do is execute the completion handler for the login event on the button you have created on your own.

Please follow below code snippet :

```
-(IBAction)btnLoginWithTwitterDidTap:(id)sender {
self.whichSocial = TW_LOGIN;
[[Twitter sharedInstance]logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
}
```

It's as simple as that

Courtesy : [Customize twitter sign in button](https://twittercommunity.com/t/can-we-customize-the-twitter-sign-in-button-with-fabric/27880)

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround to edit TWTRLoginButton font... I suppose you will be able to change text too...

```
for sub in twitterLoginButton.subviews {

    for s in sub.subviews {

        if s is UILabel {

            (s as! UILabel).font = ... font ...
            (s as! UILabel).text = ... text ...
        }
    }
}
```